# Steam API str_replace htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, mysql, api, steam

i have been making a Steam API. However i need remove htmlspecialchars from Steam Name when they login.

This is what i have done so far:

Get user name from database:

`$name = fetchinfo("name","users","steamid",$steamid)`;

When they login it should str_replace his name:

```
$name = str_replace("**something here**",'',$name);
```

How can i add htmlspecialchars for that?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the characters? This could introduce collisions in your database when "Bob&Weave" and "BobWeave" both end up in there.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to run both `str_replace` and `htmlspecialchars` on your string through nesting:

```
$name = "Tony & Sarah";
$name = htmlspecialchars( str_replace(' ','-',$name) );
// $name == "Tony-&amp;-Sarah"
```

If this doesn't match what you're looking for, an example of what you're trying to do with `str_replace` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace()` for this:

```
function replaceSpecialChars($string, $chars){
  $c = implode('\\', str_split($chars));
  return preg_replace('/['.$c.']/', '', $string);
}
$test = replaceSpecialChars('a@#bcde %8&)`', '`~!@#$%^&*()');
```

Comment: This worked fine `$name = htmlspecialchars( str_replace(' ','-',$name) );`

Comment: You never asked to replace white space with `-` characters. You already know about `htmlspecialchars`, so why was the question asked like this?